# How to loop for desired output?

Tags: matlab, matrix

HI everyone I have a matrix input program as shown below. However I fail to loop for empty or complex or NaN input. I had tired various kind of method but is still not work. Sincerely hope to get advice from you all in order to solve this problem.

```
clear;clc
m=2;
for i = 1:m
    for j = 1:m;

        element_A = ['Enter the element in row ' num2str(i) ', col ' num2str(j) ': '];
        A(i,j) = input(element_A);

        while  isnan(A(i,j)) || ~isreal(A(i,j)) || isempty(A(i,j))
            fprintf('Input not valid')
            element_A = ['Enter the element in row ' num2str(i) ', col ' num2str(j) ': '];
            A(i,j) = input(element_A);
        end        

    end
end

%% sample loop
m = str2double( input('??? : ', 's') );
while isnan(m) || ~isreal(m) || m<0
    m = str2double( input('Enter valid value : ', 's') );
end
```

Comment: Would you please specify what you  mean by "does not work". For `nan` and complex numbers your code seems to work fine; it only crashes for empty lines (pressing return without entering a number.

Comment: @H.Muster if i directly press enter without insert any numeric value or I insert the complex number i or j it will not prompt the message "Input not valid" and prompt the input message again to request me reenter. If I just press enter the process will just terminate instead of prompt again the input msg..meant it will not loop..my looping was fail)

Comment: That is because you are using `i` and `j` as indices; thus, overwriting their imaginary value.

Comment: @HebeleHododo so how should I loop it? Sincerely thanks for your help

Comment: @green: if you use something like `1 + 1i` as input complex numbers are detected correctly by your code.

Comment: @H.Muster How about pressing without entering a number? cannot be detected by isempty? If so I should use what command...thanks a lot?!

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking for NaN, complex values and empty inputs before you assign them in `A`. You can do it like this:

```
m=2;
A = zeros(m); % You do not have to do this but it will increase the performance of your code.
for idx = 1:m
    for jdx = 1:m;
        element_A = ['Enter the element in row ' num2str(idx) ', col ' num2str(jdx) ': '];
        inputElement = input(element_A);
        while isempty(inputElement) || isnan(inputElement) || ~isreal(inputElement)
            fprintf('Invalid input');
            inputElement = input(element_A);

        end
        A(idx,jdx) = inputElement;
    end
end
```

Notice that I moved `isempty` check to first place. `||` is a short circuit operator and will not check the next values is the first element gives `true`. If it is checked after, say `isnan`, it will give an error.

Comment: if I type something like  34ert it will show "Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator." at the command window and the program will terminate or I simply type a character like q or w or e... it will say that "Undefined function or variable 'q'."...could I possibly bypass all these and loop it?

Comment: @green It is probably because you started with a number. It works fine for long strings. You need to use try/catch blocks for that. I am assuming you started learning MATLAB recently. If it is not really important, I would say leave it for later.

Comment: @HebeleHododocould u just check the sample loop that I just posted in my post above..I just wonder why for that case it can bypass all and proceed the looping and it can't be applied to this current example..I really wish to understand this

Comment: @green It worked fine when I copied it to the start of my answer. What was your input?